# Issue with centering Webpage with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have done up a page for eBay, I have tested it in Explorer, Safari, Firefox, and all is well. But for some reason when I dump the code into eBay and preview it, the page is rendered off to the left hand side. I have tried all manner of searches with different types of CSS, but I have been unable to find a solution. Hence I am here. Can someone please shed some light on what the hell I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        text-align:justify;
        font-size:13px;
    }

    #container { 
        width:730px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 14;
        text-align:justify;
    }

    img{
        border:0;
    }

    a img {
        border:none;
    }

    p { padding: 0 15px 0 15px }

    .banner img{ padding: 0 5px 5px 5px; }

    #jerseyBio{
        width:730px;
        margin-bottom:5px;

    }

    #jerseyBio ul {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    #jerseyBio ul li{
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #itemPhotos{
        width:730px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    .leftSplit{
        width:360px;
        left:0px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0px 0px 10px
    }

    .rightSplit{
        width:360px;
        right:0px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0px 0px 0px
    }

    #itemPhotos img{
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #sizeChart{
        padding-bottom:0px;
        margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: since we are completely unaware of your problem i m just assuming it. Can you take one main Box container for all your HTML and give it css `style:margin: 0 auto` it will align your Box in center.

Comment: What kind of positioning are you using? Relative? Absolute? Fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can center an element in its parent container:

1. Using `margin: auto;` trick is the easiest way.
2. Using absolute positioned object, with determined height and width, inside a relatively or absolutely positioned parent:

   ```
    #parent {position: relative;}
    #child 
    {
         position: absolute; 
         height: 300px; 
         width: 300px; 
         top: 0; 
         right: 0; 
         bottom: 0; 
         left: 0; 
         margin: auto;
    }
   ```
3. [Using 50% margin for objects with unknown width and height](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are "styling" the body, try, as also Murtaza sais, to add margin:0 auto; there like this:

```
body {
     background-color: #FFF;
     text-align:justify;
     font-size:13px;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

If that does not help you could try wrapping your html code in a div and style that div with margin:0 auto;

Comment: That is insuficcient. The container (div for example) needs a width, and then you specify the `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: Yep, I wanted to add it but was too late... sorry.